# How to loop through two arrays and removing matching records in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm trying to write some simple PHP code that is able to loop through a csv of club members and a csv bank account to create a list of unpaid members.

I've followed some guides online and having some success but I've just hit a wall I can't seem to get my head round.

The code imports both csv's into separate two dimensional arrays.

then I have a for loop within a for loop, The top loop goes through the members csv and the internal loop goes through the statement csv looking for a matching record. If it finds a match it adds the member and payment details to a separate array and removes the entry from both the statement and members csv.

At the end, I should have three arrays and have output as csv files, one with the members that have paid along with the payment details, the original members csv that now only contains the members that haven't paid and the original statement csv containing any payments that haven't been matched to a member.

For some reason though when the top loop gets to row 103 it stops finding any matches in the statement csv. In playing around I found that if I comment out the line removing the element from the members csv it continues to find matches.

I can't see why removing a element form the array and immediately moving onto the next element is causing problems. I know that using unset() doesn't change the indexes which is why I re-index the array after the loop is complete.

I'm guessing I have a simple error that I'm just not seeing. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
//START - Check payments
//This section of code loops through the members and statment arrays, save the payment details to a seperate array and removes records from the original CSV's and reindexes them.
for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($memberscsv, 0); $row++) {
    //Loop through the rows of the members csv arrray.
    for ($statmentrow = 0; $statmentrow < sizeof($statmentcsv, 0); $statmentrow++) {
        //Loop through the rows of the statment csv arrray.
        
        if (strcasecmp($memberscsv[$row][2],$statmentcsv[$statmentrow][1]) == 0) {
            //If there is a matching payment record add these details to a paid database and remove records from original array.
            $paidMembers[] = [$memberscsv[$row][0], $memberscsv[$row][1], $memberscsv[$row][2], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][0], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][1], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][2], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][3], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][4], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][5], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][6], $statmentcsv[$statmentrow][7]];
            unset($memberscsv[$row]);    //<--- Commenting out this line caused the script to find all the matches.
            unset($statmentcsv[$statmentrow]);
            $statmentcsv = array_values($statmentcsv);
            //Break out of statement loop.
            break;
        }
    }
    
}
$memberscsv = array_values($memberscsv);
//END - Check payments.
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. There is currently a lot of _talk_ in your question - but no actual sample data, so that we could run this, and check for ourselves. Please provide a (reduced!) version of both of your input arrays, a couple of records each - and explain what exact result you want to get based on those, and at which point exactly it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove elements from an array that you are iterating through in a `foreach` loop, but not in a `for` loop. The for loop reevaluates the `for` expression on every iteration, while `foreach` operates on an iterator that is not affected by changes to the array in-loop.

For example, the for loop will only output two lines, while the foreach will output three.

```php
<?php
$memberscsv = [
    [1, 'bob', 'bob@test.com'],
    [2, 'alice', 'alice@test.com'],
    [3, 'frodo', 'fodo@theshire.com']
];

$statmentcsv = [
    [1, 'unknown@test.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 'alice@test.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 'fodo@theshire.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];

echo 'Remove an element by index in a for loop:'.PHP_EOL;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($memberscsv); $i++)
{
    echo json_encode($memberscsv[$i]).PHP_EOL;
    if($i==0)
    {
        unset($memberscsv[$i]);
    }
}

echo 'Remove an element by index in a foreach loop:'.PHP_EOL;
foreach($statmentcsv as $i=>$currRow)
{
    echo json_encode($statmentcsv[$i]).PHP_EOL;
    if($i==0)
    {
        unset($statmentcsv[$i]);
    }
}
```

```
Remove an element by index in a for loop:
[1,"bob","bob@test.com"]
[2,"alice","alice@test.com"]
Remove an element by index in a foreach loop:
[1,"unknown@test.com",1,2,3,4,5,6]
[2,"alice@test.com",1,2,3,4,5,6]
[3,"fodo@theshire.com",1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So that's the *why* to your problem, but there are much more efficient and easy to read ways to do what you're trying to do.

Don't be afraid to create new data structures in order to do what you need to do, there's no reason to preserve or limit yourself to only operating on the arrays that were created when the CSVs were read in.

```php
<?php
$memberscsv = [
    [1, 'bob', 'bob@test.com'],
    [2, 'alice', 'alice@test.com'],
    [3, 'frodo', 'fodo@theshire.com']
];

$statmentcsv = [
    [1, 'unknown@test.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 'alice@test.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 'fodo@theshire.com', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];

// Get the values of the common field between the members and statements
$memberKeys = array_column($memberscsv, 2);
// Create an associative array of keys to members
$memberMap  = array_combine($memberKeys, $memberscsv);

// Get the values of the common field between the members and statements
$statementKeys = array_column($statmentcsv, 1);
// Create an associative array of keys to statements
$statementMap  = array_combine($statementKeys, $statmentcsv);

// We can now easily derive the data sets we want by comparing and contrasting existing keys
$paidMembers       = array_intersect_key($memberMap, $statementMap);
$unpaidMembers     = array_diff_key($memberMap, $statementMap);
$unknownStatements = array_diff_key($statementMap, $memberMap);

//Enrich paid members with statement data - pass the row by reference so we can update it
foreach ($paidMembers as $currKey => &$currRow)
{
    $currRow = array_merge($currRow, $statementMap[$currKey]);
}
```